# Using XML Parameter from VB.NET for MS Access Table Insert/Update

Tags: xml, vb.net, ms-access

I am writing an application in VB.NET and have coded the backend using SQL Server to prove the concept - however this was done using stored procedures. As you probably know the 'engine' for SQL Server is massive. In time I want to distribute my application to individuals but wish to keep things very minimal in terms of file size and installation sets. With OLE I can simply supply an Access database file.

The stored procedures I have written in SQL use an XML string and this enables me to write many individual records to the database with a single call from my VB.NET application [PriceDataUpdate].

The equivalent in Access as far as I can see is for me to call a QUERY procedure from VB.NET **for each record** I wish to insert, which is going to dramatically slow things down.... anyone any idea how I can pass an XML string to Access in the same way I have done for SQL Server to write all the records in one call...?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need MsAccess, there is [Sql Express and LocalDb](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52679) which are lightweight and will work with your existing stored procedures.

Comment: Hey - thank you for the headsup. I am using SQL Express (not SQL Server , my mistake) and I see there is a way to connect to 'localdb' from Tools/Connect to Database in VS Express 2013. So I bind the localdb to my VS project file and I have added a 'preqrequisite' in the publish part of my projects properties to reference SQL Server 2012 LocalDB. When I build the project will VS pull my new database file that I have created into my install set...?

Comment: When you create a database you can specify where to create the .mdf and .ldf files. I've only ever used localdb for development so your installation process may need to deal with it but it can't be much different than installing the Access runtime.